# PHP: Laravel query optimization

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, optimization

I have this `query` that is `querying` through a table of more than 3 hundred thousands records. So here is the query in `Laravel 5.5`:

```
$this->select = \DB::table('transport_orders')
   ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'transport_orders.user_id', 'left')
   ->join('transport_order_price_requests', 'transport_order_price_requests.transport_order_id', '=', 'transport_orders.id', 'left')
   ->join('price_requests', 'transport_order_price_requests.price_request_id', '=', 'price_requests.id', 'left')
   ->join('order_numbers', 'transport_orders.order_number_id', '=', 'order_numbers.id', 'left')
   ->join(\DB::raw('
                (select transport_order_statuses.transport_order_id, max(transport_order_statuses.id) as last_link_id
                from transport_order_statuses
                group by transport_order_statuses.transport_order_id) as last_statuses'
            ), function ($join) {
     $join->on('transport_orders.id', '=', 'last_statuses.transport_order_id');
            })
   ->join('transport_order_statuses', 'last_statuses.last_link_id', '=', 'transport_order_statuses.id')
   ->join('statuses', 'transport_order_statuses.status_id', '=', 'statuses.id')
   ->select(
        'transport_orders.id as id',
             \DB::raw('CONCAT(users.first_name, \' \', users.last_name) as user_full_name'),
              \DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(transport_orders.pickup_date , "%Y-%m-%d") as pickup_date'),
         'transport_orders.location_name',
         'transport_orders.carrier_name',
         'transport_orders.country_name',
         'transport_orders.country_code',
         'transport_orders.category_name',
         'transport_orders.zip',
         'transport_orders.rate_type',
         'transport_orders.rate_name',
         'transport_orders.order_number_id',
         'order_numbers.order_number as order_number',
         'transport_orders.comment',
         'transport_orders.inbound',
         'transport_orders.unit',
         'transport_orders.unit_value',
         \DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(transport_orders.created_at , "%Y-%m-%d") as created_at'),
         'transport_orders.base_price',
         'transport_orders.created_at',
         'transport_orders.updated_at',
         'transport_orders.price',
         'transport_orders.stops',
         'transport_orders.stop_price',
         'transport_orders.id as id',
         'transport_orders.transport_mode as transport_mode_name',
         'statuses.status as status',
         'statuses.id as status_id',
         'transport_orders.multishipment as multishipment',
         'transport_orders.total_weight as total_weight',
         'order_numbers.simulation as simulated'
 )->where('transport_orders.is_deleting', '=', 0);
```

And after this I do:

```
$this->select->paginate($itemsPerPage);
```

Now if this `query` is to be converted to plain `MySql`, here it is:

```
select  `transport_orders`.`id` as `id`,
CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as user_full_name,
DATE_FORMAT(transport_orders.pickup_date , "%Y-%m-%d") as pickup_date,
`transport_orders`.`location_name`, `transport_orders`.`carrier_name`,
`transport_orders`.`country_name`, `transport_orders`.`country_code`,
`transport_orders`.`category_name`, `transport_orders`.`zip`,
`transport_orders`.`rate_type`, `transport_orders`.`rate_name`,
`transport_orders`.`order_number_id`, `order_numbers`.`order_number` as `order_number`,
`transport_orders`.`comment`, `transport_orders`.`inbound`, `transport_orders`.`unit`,
`transport_orders`.`unit_value`,
DATE_FORMAT(transport_orders.created_at , "%Y-%m-%d") as created_at,
`transport_orders`.`base_price`, `transport_orders`.`created_at`,
`transport_orders`.`updated_at`, `transport_orders`.`price`, `transport_orders`.`stops`,
        `transport_orders`.`stop_price`, `transport_orders`.`id` as `id`,
        `transport_orders`.`transport_mode` as `transport_mode_name`,
        `statuses`.`status` as `status`, `statuses`.`id` as `status_id`,
        `transport_orders`.`multishipment` as `multishipment`,
        `transport_orders`.`total_weight` as `total_weight`, `order_numbers`.`simulation` as `simulated`
    from  `transport_orders`
    left join  `users`  ON `users`.`id` = `transport_orders`.`user_id`
    left join  `transport_order_price_requests`  ON `transport_order_price_requests`.`transport_order_id` = `transport_orders`.`id`
    left join  `price_requests`  ON `transport_order_price_requests`.`price_request_id` = `price_requests`.`id`
    left join  `order_numbers`  ON `transport_orders`.`order_number_id` = `order_numbers`.`id`
    inner join  
    (
        SELECT  transport_order_statuses.transport_order_id, max(transport_order_statuses.id) as last_link_id
            from  transport_order_statuses
            group by  transport_order_statuses.transport_order_id
    ) as last_statuses  ON `transport_orders`.`id` = `last_statuses`.`transport_order_id`
    inner join  `transport_order_statuses`  ON `last_statuses`.`last_link_id` = `transport_order_statuses`.`id`
    inner join  `statuses`  ON `transport_order_statuses`.`status_id` = `statuses`.`id`
    where  `transport_orders`.`is_deleting` = 0
      and  `order_numbers`.`simulation` = 0
    order by  `transport_orders`.`created_at` desc
    limit  13 offset 0
```

The `Laravel` `debugbar` tells me that the query is taking more than 9 seconds. As I am using `paginate` (`Length Aware Paginator`), it also does a count so that takes another around 6 seconds. When I run the plain query in `MySql` it takes about 9-10 seconds as well. How can I optimize this query? Note that I don't want to use `simplePaginate` as it would require a whole lot of refactoring.

Comment: Just to observe, dates are "%Y-%m-%d", so DATE_FORMAT(..."%Y-%m-%d") is either redundant, or identical to DATE(...)

Answer (score 1):

These indexes may help:

```
transport_order_statuses:  (transport_order_id, id)
transport_orders:  (is_deleting, created_at)
transport_order_price_requests:  (transport_order_id, price_request_id)
```

Changing all the `LEFT JOINs` into `JOINs` may provide the same answer while giving the Optimizer more options (and confuse me less).

Because two tables are referenced in `WHERE`, the query probably has to be evaluated completed through the `WHERE` before getting to the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, there not allowing any optimizations in this area.  Getting rid of `simulation = 0` *may* speed things up (at the cost of getting too many rows).